# How to find out why joining a NAS to AD running on Samba 4.4 / Debian fails?

Tags: active-directory, debian, network-attached-storage, samba4, debian-jessie

I am currently trying to join a Seagat Black Armor 220 NAS to my Active Directory Domain (2008_R2) controlled by Samba 4.4 running on Debian Jessie. But this will fail all the time giving me the Response from the NAS:

> Failed to join domain. [NET_ERROR: Join ADS failed]

Looking in the Seagate FAQ this should mean the Domainname or the Admin Login is incorrect. I checked a thousand times but the Values i entered are correct. Furthermore the NAS was previously already Member of two other AD Domains running Samba 4.1 one with Runlevel 2003 the other with 2008_R2 and it worked perfectly. Sadly it won't give me any more Details on what is the Problem here.

By the way, any other Device can be joined without any issus.

My Question now is where are the failed join Attemps logged on the Server / Samba? Or how do i need to change the Configuration to enable logging of these events? I really need to get more information than the NAS is providing.